# python: change base class attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes

So, I have this class which keeps track of the number of instances that are created:

```
class Base(object):
    total = 0
    def __init__(self):
        <more code>
        Base.total += 1
```

Now, I want to create a derived class, but I don't want its instances to add to the total in Base. So I subtract in order to undo the adding:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Derived,self).__init__()
        Base.total -= 1
```

It works, however, it does not seem to me a good practice to access a base class attribute in the derived class. Is there a better method?

Comment: You don't have to call the `__init__` method of your base class. You can always move your `<more code>` block into a separate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid calling superclass constructor in child class. It works fine but not looking very nice

## noinspection PyMissingConstructor

class Derived(Base):

```
def __init__(self):
    <more code>
```